# After scrolling down component, how to set 'position:fixed' without reverting the component back to its original position?

Tags: css, angular

I have a component `sidebar` which the user can scroll down. If the user clicks a button (external to the component) I use `[ngClass]` to add `position:fixed` to `sidebar`, and `sidebar` returns to its' original position. How can I prevent scrolling on `sidebar` without returning `sidebar` to its' origin position?

Edit: It was recommended that I provide code to explain my problem, so I created a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n1uvhq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css).

The main pieces of the stackblitz example are the `app.component`, and the `sidebar.component`. To see my problem, scroll down on the sidebar, then click the `stopScroll` button, and see how the sidebar is moved back to its' original spot.

Comment: You should provide the code in your application that relates to the question it will help people help you find a solution to your problem.

Comment: No purely CSS solution available for this case. Javascript offers a few ways to achieve what you are describing, but yes, please share what code you have so far.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for your recommendation. I have followed it, and will continue to do so in the future. Simran, thank you as well. That makes sense and is good to know that it is not possible with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible without any crazy scripting, but it requires you specify a fixed size for the container. By changing the `overflow` property of the container, we can "lock" the scroll to a specific spot.

Take a look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isq6lq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)